# Why does emacs escape getty?

Tags: linux, bash

I create two virtual serials by

```
socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0 pty,raw,echo=0
```

in the specific case, I got /dev/pts/9 and /dev/pts/16
I then start screen on one side, in one X terminal, specifically gnome-terminal

```
 screen /dev/pts/9 9600 vt52
```

and getty on the other side (from root), in another X terminal (again, gnome-terminal)

```
getty pts/16 9600 vt52
```

I then login in the screen terminal, I can ls etc. However, when I launch emacs  (inside screen, so it's text version, not the X one) I get emacs's output on the getty's X terminal, instead of inside screen's X terminal . How is that possible? How can I fix that?

I do not know if that's related, but when I login I get

```
-bash: cannot set terminal process group (64718): Inappropriate ioctl for device
-bash: no job control in this shell
```

Comment: (1) The `DISPLAY` environment variable controls which X server is connected to. (2) It's possible your setup is configured to use `emacsclient` or similar to connect to a preexisting copy of emacs. (3) A lot of details that matter aren't really explicitly included, and it's not completely clear if it's a question that's well-suited to be here rather than on [unix.se].

Comment: would you kindly state which details matter? I can edit the question to reflect that. And no, emacs is not a link to emacsclient

Comment: If I am not mistaken, DISPLAY matters only for programs using the  X  server. In this case, emacs is launching as a text interface program, not as an X program.

Comment: Why do you keep talking about X in the question if it's irrelevant? Easier to just talk about terminals. Anyhow -- have you ruled out emacsclient? Also, what's the output of the `tty` command in each shell?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy see the answer

Answer (score 1):

The answer was provided by Andres Navarro (https://github.com/AndresNavarro82). It is necessary to use setsid, i.e.

```
sudo setsid getty pts/16 9600 vt52
```